# "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network."

Tags: google-search, captcha

I frequently see the below message when using Google Search:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and
>   not a robot. Why did this happen?
>
> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming
>   from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the
>   Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests
>   stop. In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue
>   to use our services.
>
> This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser
>   plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. If you share your
>   network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different
>   computer using the same IP address may be responsible. Learn more
>
> Sometimes you may be asked to solve the CAPTCHA if you are using
>   advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very
>   quickly.

Then I have to solve a CAPTCHA which I normally get incorrect and then have to solve another one. I don't have any malware or suspicious plugins.  It seems to frequently happen during peak hour, both in Windows and OS X using Firefox.

I think the problem is to do with my ISP using a [shared IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:202.156.6.54) for all users. I have filed a support request with Google without any luck.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this help article from Google: [Unusual traffic from your computer network
](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86640)

Comment: Google makes its living by profiling us - and our searches.
I got the "Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network" message using Linux, with no trujans, virii and my own server - but using Opera Browser with a somewhat personalised search script.
There *was* no unusual traffic. However, Google likes to return search results consistent with my own purchasing habits. It was unable to profile me, so asked me to prove I am indeed a person.
Google's claims that there are viruses involved would indeed be responsible had there been "unusual traffic." However, try setting up

Comment: However, try setting up some *unusual traffic* of your own (connection keepers, whatever) and Google will never see any of it. Only you and your ISP will.

Comment: @user18016 comment directed me into the fact that the queries coming from Opera 17 (default install) from the URL bar are classified as "unusual". It seems that **turning instant search off** fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

If you think that you are being blocked because your ISP share IPs among a lot of users (shared public IP address):

1. ask your ISP if they could assign you

   1. to a different group of users
   2. a dedicated IP address
2. change of ISP.

## Explanation

From ["Unusual traffic from your computer network"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)

> ### I shouldn't be getting blocked
>
> Google Search blocks IPs, IP ranges, and in some cases, whole ISPs,
>   when a large percent of the traffic entering our networks is abusive.
>
> If the blocking started within the past few weeks, it is likely to be
>   related to the use of the "Hola VPN" browser plugin, or a program for
>   Mac/Win/Android/iOS. The best thing to do is to uninstall the Hola VPN
>   from your computer or network.
>
> If you are an Internet Service Provider (ISP), explain to your users
>   why it is important for them to uninstall this type of VPN. When the
>   abuse hitting our network stops, we automatically stop blocking the
>   IP(s)/ISP(s) that were sending the bad traffic. Learn more about [Hola
>   VPNs here](http://www.adios-hola.org/).
>
> Unfortunately, sometimes non-Hola traffic gets looped in with the
>   abusive traffic. We are working on a way to change our protections so
>   that we'll only block Hola traffic in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There can be other reasons besides malware or trojans on your computer. If your computer is a part of an intranet/ protected network, all requests originating from within the intranet (via proxy) would appear to Google as coming from the same IP address. As a result, it would give the message for unusual amount of traffic.

Comment: Yes that is pretty must my suspicion stated in my question. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: nope... i better delete this as an answer and put it as a comment