# How to repeatedly perform Google search without being asked for human verification?

Tags: google-search, automation, recaptcha

Suppose that you want to perform repeated Google search through automation, then, once every 20-30 searches, google might ask you for human verification, which is very hard for a non-human agent to complete.

How do you repeatedly perform Google search with minimal hassle?

---

Here is what I tried to avoid the human verification:

1. Change LAN IP: Does not work at most of the times.
2. Use a VPN to switch IP: works but I don't have enough IP address.
3. Change browser: works inconsistently.

---

PS: Sincerely apologize that I did not read the on-topic info before I post my first question.

Comment: Related [Is there a way to use Google's advanced search parameters without triggering the CAPTCHA test?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124981/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you should have in mind is that Google terms of services doesn't allow to do automated search queries. If you really need to do automated searches, then you should use another service, specially if you are looking to this for a long time and "hassle" free.

The above because despite if the user repeatedly do searches automatically or manually, Google might block the user and others using the same network from web searching. A soft measure is to present a *reCAPTCHA* but on the old official Google Help Forum there were reports that Google goes a bit beyond that by presenting even to all the users of the same ISP a message like "we detected that your network is doing automated searches ask for help to you network administrator" and point the users to the related help article. I know this because I'm a Top Contributor (now we are called Product Experts) and had use to participate very frequently on on threads about this and have scaled several them for attention of the community manager and specialists.

Related

- ["Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network."](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22355/88163)
- [How can I get Google to stop thinking I'm a Bot?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29034/88163)
- [Google search thinks I'm a robot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115116/88163)
- [Is there a way to use Google's advanced search parameters without triggering the CAPTCHA test?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124981/88163)
- [How to fight against Google Captchas appearing on searches from a school network?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136480/88163)

*From Server Fault*

- [Google is blocking our requests due to “automated queries”; what's the best way to find out why?](https://serverfault.com/q/151417/300641)

*From Stack Overflow*

- [How to solve a reCaptcha in advance using a web scraper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43557112/1595451)